# Derivation of the formula of the variance of a linear gaussian

Tags: normal-distribution, variance, linear, graphical-model

I'm trying to understand this formula for the variance in Kohler's PGM text. It's theorem 7.3:

Let $Y$ be a linear Gaussian  of parents $X_1 .. X_k$:
$$p(Y|X) = \mathcal{N}(\beta_0 + \beta^T\mathbf{x}; \sigma^2)$$

Assume that $X_i .. X_k$ are jointly Gaussian with distribution $\mathcal{N}(\mathbf{u}, \Sigma)$ Then:

The distribution of $Y$ is such that:

$$\sigma^2_{Y} = \sigma^2 + \beta^T \Sigma \beta$$

How is this variance derived? I assume the sum of the variance of gaussians is equal to its linear sum plus the covariance. In this case, it seems like we're summing a weighted variance, where the coefficients are the weights. However, why is it then not just:

$$\sigma^2_{Y} = \sigma^2 + \beta^2 \Sigma$$

That would follow the usual variance formula $Var(Ax + By) = A^2Var(x) + B^2Var(Y)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is the law of total variance formula $\operatorname{Var}(Y) = \operatorname{Var}(E[Y|X]) + E[\operatorname{Var}(Y|X)]$.

By assumption, $E[Y|X] = \beta_0 + \beta'X, \operatorname{Var}(Y|X) = \sigma^2$.  It then follows by $X \sim N(\mu, \Sigma)$ that $\beta_0 + \beta'X \sim N(\beta_0 + \beta'\mu, \beta'\Sigma\beta)$, whence
\begin{align}
\operatorname{Var}(Y) = \operatorname{Var}(E[Y|X]) + E[\operatorname{Var}(Y|X)] = \beta'\Sigma\beta + \sigma^2.
\end{align}

Comment: I still don't see the derivation here. How did you get the first term of the decomposition (the variance explained: Var(E[Y|X]))

Comment: @Estimatetheestimators Because $E[Y|X] = \beta_0 + \beta'X \sim N(\beta_0 + \beta'\mu, \beta'\Sigma\beta)$ (as derived in the answer), you can directly read off the variance of $E[Y|X]$ is $\beta'\Sigma\beta$ -- just as simple as if $\xi \sim N(\eta, \tau^2)$, then $\operatorname{Var}(\xi) = \tau^2$.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you need to put the covariance *between* the two betas, and why one needs to be transposed (the superscript "T" on the first one) is because covariance is a *matrix*, and beta is a *vector*, whereas variance is always a *scalar* (except in situations where Y is itself a matrix of random variables). Specifically, if there are n Gaussians, the covariance is nxn and beta is a n-dimensional column vector.

In your suggested formula, "squaring" beta--which amounts to a dot product of beta with itself, would give a scalar, which when multiplied by the nxn covariance matrix would give you an nxn matrix, which isn't what you want.

If you expand out the matrix product in the second term of the actual result, you in fact get a sum of nxn weighted terms, like your second term, one for each *pair* of Gaussians (including pairs where both are the same Gaussian, which come from the diagonal elements of the covariance). These diagonal terms give you a weighted sum of the individual variances, while the off-diagonal terms give you the "extra" variance due to cross-correlation between different Gaussians.

Comment: This is so insightful. Is there any other way to see or appreciate these relationships? I tried it out and it now makes a lot of sense. Just visualizng all the row and then column muplitications of the betas made it stick.